# setting stored session value in selectbox and display remaining items using php

Tags: php

I have a select box and it iterates using foreach loop in php.I can select a value and submit this to server.When Next time If I am coming to this page,I need to display the selected value in selectbox and also other items.

I have done session for storing select text values but not getting an idea how to check for session value inside foreach.I use chosen select box,its a jquery plugin select box.

```
<select data-placeholder="Choose a city"    class="form-control chosen-select person" tabindex="2"> <option value=""></option>
            <?php  foreach($city->entities as $row) {

    echo '<option value="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->name.'</option>';
} ?></select>
```

Comment: Please do share some code ..

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this way

```
<select data-placeholder="Choose a city"    class="form-control chosen-select person" tabindex="2"> <option value=""></option>
            <?php  foreach($city->entities as $row) {
if($row->name==$sesssion_value)
    echo '<option selected='selected' value="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->name.'</option>';
else
 echo '<option value="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->name.'</option>';
} ?></select>
```